# How convert Gregorian to Chinese Lunar Calendar?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to build an android app using Greogorian Calendar to Chinese Lunar Calendar.

I don't know how to convert from Gregorian to Chinese Calendar. How can I do this?

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity, Fixed formatting, Touched up grammar.

Comment: Thanks Adrian & Alex for the correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/ibm/icu/util/ChineseCalendar.java.html

There is a contructor:

```
public ChineseCalendar(Date date) ...
```

### Links:

Doc: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/ChineseCalendar.html

Source: http://site.icu-project.org/download

Comment: here is the code http://www.docjar.com/src/api/com/ibm/icu/util/ChineseCalendar.java

Answer (score 3):

**Conversion from gregorian to chinese**

I just released a new version of Time4J (v4.35, but use [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A)-v3.40-2018b on Android) which supports the [Chinese calendar](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/ChineseCalendar.html). The conversion from gregorian to chinese lunisolar calendar can be done in a straight forward way:

```
PlainDate gregorian = PlainDate.nowInSystemTime(); // 2018-03-07
ChineseCalendar cc = gregorian.transform(ChineseCalendar.axis());
System.out.println(cc); // chinese[wu-xu(2018)-1-21]
```

The documentation of the Chinese calendar also contains examples how to format or parse it in many localized ways.

**Special design requirements for the display on Android**

Keep also in mind that the Chinese calendar contains elements which don't exist in gregorian calendar, for example **cyclic years**, **leap months** or **solar terms** (a generalization of our astronomical seasons). Time4J/A can format it, but it is specific for the calendar. This is relevant if you have thought about a generic calendar display which shall be universally applicable for all calendars. It is probably better to make a specific display for the Chinese calendar on Android so other important informations like cyclic years in text form or solar terms can still be displayed, too.

**Comparison to ICU4J**

Main differences:

- API-style: ICU4J has adopted the old world of `java.util.Calendar` while Time4J/A follows a domain-driven approach
- immutability feature (ICU4J-calendar-class is NOT immutable in contrast to Time4J/A)
- solar terms (ICU4J does not seem to have any support for this feature)
- accuracy (ICU4J uses an astronomy module based on the book of Peter Duffet/Smith, while Time4J/A is mainly based on the work of Jean Meeus)

While some people still like the old-fashioned-style of ICU4J, I am most worried about the accuracy of ICU4J. As reference, you can watch the data published by [Hongkong observatory](http://www.hko.gov.hk/gts/time/calendar/pdf/2018e.pdf) for the year 2018. ICU4J deviates from Hongkong data already on 2018-11-07 (for a whole month, the date is wrong by one day!). Proof using the following code:

```
DateFormat df = 
    DateFormat.getDateInstance(
        DateFormat.FULL, 
        ULocale.forLanguageTag("en-u-ca-chinese"));
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
sf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai"));

ChineseCalendar cc = new ChineseCalendar(78, 35, 0, 0, 1);
System.out.println(df.format(cc.getTime())); // Friday, First Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    cc.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    System.out.print(df.format(cc.getTime()));
    System.out.println("=>" + sf.format(cc.getTime()));
}
```

Output (pay attention to line in November):

```
Saturday, Second Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2018-03-17
Monday, Third Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2018-04-16
Tuesday, Fourth Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2018-05-15
Thursday, Fifth Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2018-06-14
Friday, Sixth Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2018-07-13
Saturday, Seventh Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2018-08-11
Monday, Eighth Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2018-09-10
Tuesday, Ninth Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2018-10-09
Wednesday, Tenth Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2018-11-07
Friday, Eleventh Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2018-12-07
Sunday, Twelfth Month 1, 2018(wu-xu)=>2019-01-06
Tuesday, First Month 1, 2019(ji-hai)=>2019-02-05
Thursday, Second Month 1, 2019(ji-hai)=>2019-03-07
```

See also the old [unsolved issue on the bug-tracker of ICU4J](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/10893), many more dates in the future are wrong. Sure, astronomical calculations cannot be predicted in a strict way for the future, but the first date where Time4J/A deviates from Hongkong data is the year 2057 (calculated as only 37 seconds after local midnight) and not already the present year 2018 like in ICU4J. So I would advise against ICU4J as long as they have not corrected their astronomy module and cannot even be correct for the actual year.

To be realistic in far future, we don't know who is right for the year 2057, and even the Hongkong observatory is explicitly uncertain at this date:

> If the time of new moon (first day of the lunar month) or solar term
>   is close to midnight, the dates of the relevant lunar month or solar
>   term in the "Conversion Table" may have a discrepancy of one day. Such
>   situation will occur on the new moons on 28 September 2057 [...]