# Why does Java 8 DateTimeFormatter allows an incorrect month value in ResolverStyle.STRICT mode?

Tags: java-8, java-time, datetime-parsing

Why does this test pass, while the month value is obviously invalid (13)?

```
@Test
public void test() {

    String format = "uuuuMM";

    String value = "201713";

     DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
        .parse(value);

}
```

When using a temporal query, the expected `DateTimeParseException` is thrown:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
    .parse(value, YearMonth::from);
```

What happens when no `TemporalQuery` is specified?

---

EDIT: the 13 value seems to be a special one, as I learned thanks to the answer of ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ (see [Undecimber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecimber)).

But the exception is not thrown even with another value, like 50:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    String format = "uuuuMM";

    String value = "201750";

     DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
        .parse(value);

}
```

Comment: Related (but certainly not the same): [What does Calendar.UNDECIMBER do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716517/what-does-calendar-undecimber-do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made some debugging here and found that part of the parsing process is to check the fields against the formatter's chronology.

When you create a `DateTimeFormatter`, [by default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#resolving) it uses an [`IsoChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoChronology.html), which is used to resolve the date fields. During this resolving phase, [the method `java.time.chrono.AbstractChronology::resolveDate`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/chrono/AbstractChronology.java#AbstractChronology.resolveDate%28java.util.Map%2Cjava.time.format.ResolverStyle%29) is called.

If you look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/chrono/AbstractChronology.java#AbstractChronology.resolveDate%28java.util.Map%2Cjava.time.format.ResolverStyle%29), you'll see the following logic:

```
if (fieldValues.containsKey(YEAR)) {
    if (fieldValues.containsKey(MONTH_OF_YEAR)) {
        if (fieldValues.containsKey(DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
            return resolveYMD(fieldValues, resolverStyle);
        }
....
return null;
```

As the input has only the **year** and **month** fields, `fieldValues.containsKey(DAY_OF_MONTH)` returns `false`, the method returns `null` and no other check is made as you can see in the [`Parsed` class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/format/Parsed.java#Parsed.resolveDateFields%28%29).

So, when parsing `201750` or `201713` without a `TemporalQuery`, no additional check is made because of the logic above, and the `parse` method returns a `java.time.format.Parsed` object, as you can see by the following code:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMM").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
TemporalAccessor parsed = fmt.parse("201750");
System.out.println(parsed.getClass());
System.out.println(parsed);
```

The output is:

> class java.time.format.Parsed
>   {Year=2017, MonthOfYear=50},ISO

Note that the type of the returned object is `java.time.format.Parsed` and printing it shows the fields that were parsed (year and month).

When you call `parse` with a `TemporalQuery`, though, the `Parsed` object is passed to the query and its fields are validated (of course it depends on the query, but the API built-in ones always validate).

In the case of `YearMonth::from`, it checks if the year and month are valid using the respective `ChronoField`'s ([MONTH_OF_YEAR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#MONTH_OF_YEAR) and [YEAR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#YEAR)) and the month field accepts only values [from 1 to 12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#MONTH_OF_YEAR).

That's why just calling `parse(value)` doesn't throw an exception, but calling with a `TemporalQuery` does.

---

Just to check the logic above when all the date fields (year, month and day) are present:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
fmt.parse("20175010");
```

This throws:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20175010' could not be parsed: **Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 50**

As all the date fields are present, `fieldValues.containsKey(DAY_OF_MONTH)` returns `true` and now it checks if it's a valid date (using the [`resolveYMD` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/chrono/AbstractChronology.java#AbstractChronology.resolveYMD%28java.util.Map%2Cjava.time.format.ResolverStyle%29)).

Comment: Nicely detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

The month 13 is called : [*Undecimber*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecimber)

The *gregorian* calendar that many of us use allows *12* months only but java includes support for calendars which permit thirteen months so it depends on what calendar system you are talking about

For example, the actual maximum value of the MONTH field is *12* in some years, and *13* in other years in the *Hebrew* calendar system. So the month 13 is valid

Comment: Ok for the 13 value, I didn't know that, but the exception is not throw even with another value (changed it to 50).

Answer (score 1):

It is a little odd that an exception is not thrown when `parse` is called without a given `TemporalQuery`. Some of the documentation for the single argument `parse` method:

> This parses the entire text producing a temporal object. It is typically more useful to use parse(CharSequence, TemporalQuery). The result of this method is TemporalAccessor which has been resolved, applying basic validation checks to help ensure a valid date-time.

Note that it says it is "typically more useful to use parse(CharSequence, TemporalQuery)". In your examples, `parse` is returning a `java.time.format.Parsed` object, which is not really used for anything other than creating a different `TemporalAccessor`.

Note that if you try to create a `YearMonth` from the returned value, an exception is thrown:

```
YearMonth.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT).parse(value));
```

throws

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain YearMonth from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2017, MonthOfYear=50},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.YearMonth.from(YearMonth.java:263)
    at anl.nfolds.Test.main(Test.java:21)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 50
    at java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor.get(TemporalAccessor.java:224)
    at java.time.YearMonth.from(YearMonth.java:260)
... 1 more
```

Documentation for `Parsed`:

> A store of parsed data.
>
> This class is used during parsing to collect the data. Part of the parsing process involves handling optional blocks and multiple copies of the data get created to support the necessary backtracking.
>
> Once parsing is completed, this class can be used as the resultant TemporalAccessor. In most cases, it is only exposed once the fields have been resolved.
>
> Since:1.8
>
> @implSpecThis class is a mutable context intended for use from a single thread. Usage of the class is thread-safe within standard parsing as a new instance of this class is automatically created for each parse and parsing is single-threaded